# How can i increase value of x in function?

Tags: c++

**C++ Program: -** I know that in the function definition, x is not passed so it would get error message but i want to increase in function, so what can i do?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
fun(int& p)
{
    cout << p;
    x++;
}
int main()
{
    int x = 15;
    int c = 1;
    fun(c);
    cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You *could* make it a global variable. What are you *really* trying to achieve here?

Comment: You *can* pass it too

Comment: If `fun` needs to change `x` then pass `x` by reference to `fun`.

Comment: How can i pass it

Comment: By changing the function to `fun(int &p, int &x)` and call it as `fun(c, x);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either set `x` as a global variable or you can also pass it to your function.
`fun(int &p, int &x)` and then call it from `main`.

Answer (score 1):

The value of variable `x` is undefined for `fun()` and you should go through a book for basics.

The only method if you just want to manipulate the same variables, is using reference variables as parameters and then you can directly modify its original values.

Refined version of your program for accessing and manipulating the data with functions:

```
#include <iostream>

void fun(int &, int &);

int main(void) {
    int x = 15;
    int c = 1;

    fun(c, x); // c is printed "1" and x increments with 1

    std::cout << x << std::endl; // new value of x prints

    return 0;
}

void fun(int & p, int & x) {
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
    x++; // increments original x
}
```

**Note:** Alternatively, you can declare your required variable in global scope by putting them outside of all the functions and underneath the header declaration, so that they'll be visible to the entire program but remember that you must need to use reference for changing the variable values for the whole program.